# Strikethrough selected text inside an EditText

Tags: android

Is it possible to set the selected style of EditText to strikethrough in Android.
Can anybody show me sample code to do this?

Comment: That's for textview right?

Comment: Yes, but also interpret the content / answer. To display it, you need to use a RichText display, EditText is not RichText capable.

Answer (score 1):

> #### How to strikethrough TextView text programmatically in Android
>
> **activity_main.xml**
>
> ```
> <RelativeLayout
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:id="@+id/rl"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:padding="16dp"
>     tools:context=".MainActivity"
>     android:background="@android:color/white"
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/tv"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Sample TextView...\nSecond line of TextView"
>         android:padding="15dp"
>         android:textSize="25dp"
>         android:textColor="#ff9c308c"
>         />
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/btn"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Set Text Strike Through"
>         android:layout_below="@id/tv"
>         />
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```
>
> **MainActivity.java**
>
> ```
> package com.cfsuman.me.androidcodesnippets;
>
> import android.graphics.Paint;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.widget.Button;
> import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
> import android.widget.TextView;
>
> public class MainActivity extends Activity{
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>         // Get the widgets reference from XML layout
>         RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
>         final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
>         Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
>
>         // Set a click listener for Button widget
>         btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>
>                 /*
>                     public int getPaintFlags ()
>                         Returns
>                     the flags on the Paint being used to display the text.
>
>                     setPaintFlags(int flags)
>                         Sets flags on the Paint being used to display the text and
>                         reflows the text if they are different from the old flags.
>
>                     STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
>                      Paint flag that applies a strike-through decoration to drawn text.
>                  */
>
>                 // Set TextView text strike through
>                 tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags()|     Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
>             }
>         });
>     }
> }
> ```

From: https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-textview-strikethrough.html

Comment: This answer can realistically be reduced to a single line of code, `tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);`

Comment: This is also for a `TextView`, not an `EditText` as OP has asked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {




    EditText editText;

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.search_edit_frame);

        editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {

                    if (editText.hasSelection()) {
                        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString())){
                            final int selStart = editText.getSelectionStart();
                            final int selEnd = editText.getSelectionEnd();
                            SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(editText.getText().toString());
                            spannableString.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), selStart, selEnd, 0);

                            editText.setText(spannableString);
                            return false;
                        }

                    }


                }
                return false;
            }
        });


    }


}
```

**LAYOUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rotate">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_edit_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Nilesh Rathod"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

can be done by just setting paint flags for editText.

```
editText.paintFlags = Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
```

To remove set,

```
editText.paintFlags = Paint.CURSOR_AFTER
```